# Report Table of contents layers

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, report

I have a `\subsubsection` in the table of contents (`ToC`). It is layered correctly in the table, however for some reason the section number doesn't appear. Every other section appears fine. Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` in the document preamble, i.e. before `\begin{document}` and recompile (twice, ideally!). Normally only parts, chapters, sections are used in the `ToC`, but with the counter `tocdepth` set to 3 `subsubsection` is added too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Still doesn't seem to work though. The Table reached 1.3 - 1.3.1, then instead of 1.3.1.1 - there's no number, the text is indented correctly however. I have also tried with tocdepth of more than 3 with no result.

Comment: Please add your code to the question above then!

Comment: Do you mean the section number in the running text? Try `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` then

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean @ChristianHupfer - That worked great - Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be settled in comments

Answer (score 1):

There are two counters determining the look of the ToC and if the section levels are numbered in the running text

`tocdepth` decides which `depth` of sectioning appears in the ToC, the larger the number the deeper the sections do appear in the ToC:

`\setcounter{tocdepth}{-1}` does allow only `part`, the numbers from `1` to `6` are used for `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph` and `subparagraph`.

Other classes may define other numbers, say `-2` for the `book` level in `memoir`.

The other important counter is `secnumdepth` -- its value decides up to a certain depth the section numbers (say `1.2.3` etc.) appear in the running text. The depth values are the same as for `tocdepth`.